# Build a conda package relying on an apt library

Tags: python, package, anaconda, apt-get, conda

I am building a scientific python project that relies on a python package  (`scikits.sparse`) providing a binding to a C/Fortran library (`libsuitesparse-dev`) that can be installed through `apt-get` or `yum` but is virtually impossible to properly install manually.

I would like to make my package available to users on all the platforms and the best way I can see to do it is to use a conda package build with `conda skeleton` and then translate to other platforms. However I am not sure how well conda will manage external library dependencies from `apt-get` and was wondering if I needed to do anything else to make it work in addition to the [official instructions](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure how well conda will manage external library dependencies from apt-get

[`conda`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) will not managed external libraries through [`apt-get`](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt)  but through it's own package management system.

[`apt`](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt) and [`conda`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) are two different and independant package management systems. One is the official debian/ubuntu package manager and the other is an additional package manager such as [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) or [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/). Each of them will have their own set of installed packages and their own database.

You can distribute your project through 
[`apt`](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt) or [`conda`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) or even both, but your users will have to choose one channel of distribution.

There is already a [conda recipe for the scikits.sparse library](https://github.com/menpo/conda-recipes/blob/master/scikits-sparse/meta.yaml) you can install it via

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo scikits.sparse
```

If you want to include it in one of your recipe you have to add the menpo channel in your `.condarc`:

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - menpo
```

Then in your recipe you can require scikits.sparse such as:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - scikits.sparse
```

Comment: The question is more how I can re-package third-party binaries distributed through `apt` into `conda`

Comment: @chiffa See my edit, I think it solves your problem.